# Is it possible to destructure some properties and also assign/pass the entire object within a single assignment expression of a map callback function?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring

For example, say I am mapping an array of objects:

```
arrayOfPeople.map( ({ firstname, lastname }) => {
  // 2 variables scoped here: firstname, lastname
})
```

I understand that I could have (similarly) done the following:

```
arrayOfPeople.map(person => {
  const { firstname, lastname } = person
  // except now I actually have 3 variables scoped here: person, firstname, lastname
})
```

Is there a syntax for assigning all 3 variables (i.e. both the properties and the entire object) like in the second example, but where the assignments/destructuring takes place inside the parenthesis where the *paramaters* are?

Perhaps, something like this:

```
arrayOfPeople.map( ({ person = { /* ...entireObject */ }, firstname, lastname }) => {
 // 3 variables scoped here: person, firstname, lastname
})
```

I realize that it is a difference of a single line of code, but I'm curious if this is possible.

Thanks

EDIT: Just to clarify, the objects being mapped over in the array (i.e. the "person") has more properties than just the firstname and lastname and I want access to the entire object, including firstname and lastname.

Comment: I think that's not possible, however you could do `({firstname, lastname}, i, person)` and then access inside `person[i]`.

Comment: Okay, this is a good compromise if there truly is no way of assigning the passed object in the first argument. I forgot about the 3rd argument of the map callback being the entire array that map was called upon. Thanks

Comment: I personally would go with the way you did it with destructuring on the first line of the function. It's clearer.

Comment: I understand. I was just saying that since there isn't a nice concise syntax, go with the clear version rather than the one that uses a parameter that everyone forgets. That solution also only applies to the iteration functions, not destructuring in general.

Comment: Sorry, deleted the comment about realizing it was obscure, but just curious... I agree that it is more clear and concise due to conformance to norms. I just think it would be nice if all of the iterated object destructuring could take place before the body of the callback. It would be easier to recognize that the destructuring is not from some object external to the callback scope. Currently, you see the `const { firstname, lastname, ... , etc } = person` but you can't immediately recognize what the source object is until you look at `= person`. What if it was `= aDifferentPerson`?

Comment: Not trying to start a long discussion or be particular, I was just curious if it was possible. Appreciate the comments.

Answer (score 1):

There's **no way** to get the object as it is, and destructure it in a single statement.

But, if you want only its undestructured properties, and not the destructured ones, the object's prototype, etc.; then you can use the rest syntax (using the familiar `...` notation):

```js
arrayOfPeople.map( ({ firstname, lastname, ...rest}) => {
  // 3 variables scoped here: firstname, lastname, rest
})
```

Test it here:

```js
const original = {
  foo: 1,
  bar: 2,
  get baz(){
    return 3
  }
}

const {
  foo,
  ...rest
} = original

console.log(foo)      //1
console.log(rest.bar) //2

console.log(rest.foo) //undefined - it has been destructured
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(rest, 'baz')) //No longer a getter
```

```css
/* Just to make console fill the available space */
.as-console-wrapper{ max-height: 100% !important; }
```